# why input accept=".txt" not working in firefox 26

Tags: csv, file-upload, cross-browser

I am trying to upload .CSV and .XLs file to my web application using,

```
    <table border='1'>
<tr>
   <td>   
      Remember you can upload only CSV and xls files. max size = 15mb       
   </td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td>
      <input type="file" name="filename" id="filename"
      accept=".csv,.xls" value=""/>  

     <input type="file" name="pic" accept="video/*">                                                         
   </td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td>
      <input type="Button" value="Save File" onclick=CheckFileName(); />
   </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

But "accept=".csv,.xls" working fine in **chrome** not in **firefox 26**.

where i am wrong? how to fix this one?

Note : i can do this file validation using jscript but i want to use accept="" instead of script.

Comment: can you use `*.csv,*.xls`

Comment: @schlagi123 i tried but no use!

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input#Browser_compatibility lists `accept=[file extension]` as `Not supported` for Firefox …

Comment: This is supported from FireFox 37.